# SSRS Preset or Custom Date Selection on Report

Tags: date, reporting-services

I currently have a report with the ability to select a start and end date. I was curious if you could make have both preset and the option for a custom selection

Selection:

Current Week, or
Previous Week, or
Custom Date Range.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [cascading parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-cascading-parameters-to-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017).

The link above seems to focus more on getting your cascading parameter values from a query, but you probably don't want that for a date - as far as I am aware, setting Available Values for a date parameter limits you to a dropdown list of dates, instead of the calendar which is generally easier to use. It is still a good background on how cascading parameters work though.

To do this with expressions for the default start/end date, you would basically want the first parameter to be a choice between "Current Week", "Previous Week", and "Custom Date Range". You would display those labels to the user, but the values can be whatever you want - for my test I just used 1, 2, and 3.

[image: first parameter]

Then, you would set up 2 more parameters, one for the start date and one for the end date. Make sure the data type is Date. You will want to set up default values for these based on the value of the first parameter. I would do this with an expression such as the expression below for the start date. You also may need to modify this a bit depending on how you define the week - is the "Current Week" just the previous 7 days, or is it the latest Monday through today, or something else, etc.

```
=Switch(
    Parameters!FirstParam.Value = 1, DateAdd("d", -7, Today()),
    Parameters!FirstParam.Value = 2, DateAdd("d", -14, Today())
)
```

In this case, you don't even need to account for the 3rd option, because if the user wants a custom date range then you do not want the start and end date to fill in with any default values. You would need a similar expression for the default end date as well.

Since you want the user to be able to enter a custom range as well if they were to select the third option, you do not want to fill in the Available Values for the start/end date parameters, as the user would then not be able to select any date (at least as far as I am aware - if there is a workaround to that, I would love to see it, as that would be something I would like to use myself).

A possible downside to this approach is that if the user begins by selecting Current Week and then changes their mind to Previous Week, the start/end dates will not change to the Previous Week. You can read more about why this happens [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c24a881f-f22c-481a-91d3-d4b1082f2f78/parameter-change-does-not-refresh-default-values-of-dependent-parameters?forum=sqlreportingservices), but essentially: since the values that are already filled in after selecting Current Week are still valid (they are dates, which is the only criteria for those parameters since no available values are set up), they will not refresh after changing the selection. The fix for this is to define the Available Values, but as mentioned above, this will then stop the user from entering a custom date range.